# iPad you tube video

Tags: ipad

I am developing an ipad application which supports only portrait mode, but it has a feature to play you tube videos. I am playing them on webview.

How do I support landscape orientation for you tube videos when view controller supports only portrait mode?

Comment: Is this a native application or a web app?

Comment: I am getting you tube video urls from server and playing the video in app